# Plot Overlapping Histograms Using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a .csv file (csv_test_1.csv) that is in this format:

```
durum_before_length,durum_before_reads,durum_after_length,durum_after_reads
0,0,0,0
10,0,10,0
20,0,20,0
30,0,30,1
40,0,40,4
50,0,50,5
60,0,60,0
70,0,70,1
80,0,80,4
90,0,90,1
100,4840,100,4704
110,4817,110,4706
120,4983,120,4860
130,4997,130,4851
140,5142,140,4980
150,5363,150,5192
160,5756,160,5530
170,6054,170,5725
180,6335,180,5989
190,7051,190,6651
200,9003,200,7157
210,8446,210,7812
220,9088,220,8314
230,9761,230,8955
240,10637,240,9660
250,11659,250,10408
260,12572,260,11178
270,13139,270,11538
280,13985,280,11950
290,113552,290,14304
300,954175,300,16383
,,310,17230
,,320,18368
,,330,19158
,,340,19733
,,350,20754
,,360,21698
,,370,21991
,,380,21937
,,390,22473
,,400,22655
,,410,22497
,,420,22460
,,430,22488
,,440,21941
,,450,21884
,,460,21350
,,470,21066
,,480,20812
,,490,19901
,,500,19716
,,510,19374
,,520,19000
,,530,18245
,,540,17220
,,550,15713
,,560,14042
,,570,11932
,,580,7204
,,590,29
```

You can see that the second two columns are longer than the first two columns. I would like to plot two overlapping histograms: the first histogram will be the first column as the x values plotted against the second column as the y-values, and the second histogram will be the third column as the x values plotted against the fourth column as the y-values.

I am thinking of using seaborn because it makes nice looking plots.  The code I have thus far is as shown below. From here, I have no idea how to specify the x and y values and how to generate two overlapping histograms on the same plot. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

read_data = read_csv("csv_test_1.csv")
sns.set(style="white", palette="muted")
sns.despine()
plt.hist(read_data, normed=False)
plt.xlabel("Read Length")
plt.ylabel("Number of Reads")
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. What do you mean when you say `the first histogram will be the first column as the x values plotted against the second column as the y-values`. Sounds like a scatter plot, not a histogram. If you want to plot a histogram it would be a 2D histogram. But you cannot overlap 2D histograms when plotted in a 2D plane.

Comment: Sorry to not be more clear. I have attached a link to an image showing an example of what I would like to do. http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/plotting_distributions_11_0.png

Comment: Histograms plot the distribution of your data. You can plot 2 columns of your data by two 1D histograms.

Comment: Ok, thank you! For my histograms, I guess what I unsure of is how to specify the bins and the frequency in each bin. In this case, the bins will be the first column for one histogram, and the third column for the second histogram. The frequencies in each bin are the second and fourth columns, respectively.

Comment: If you already have the bins and frequency, you should use `plt.bar` directly. `plt.hist` is just a wrapper that computes the bins and frequencies and then draws a bar plot.